# call a function and explicitly return in a single line?

Tags: coffeescript

Is it possible to call a function and return on the same line:

```
foo() and return if conditon == true
```

Instead of splitting to multiple lines? I get the following error with `return` highlighted when I try:

```
error: cannot use a pure statement in an expression
```

Comment: Are you calling the function foo() or trying to define it. Additionally if you are trying to call the function what does foo() return? A string, integer, boolean, etc?

Comment: calling it, that's why there are () after the function

Comment: What does `foo` return?

Comment: In my case foo() does not return anything meaningful, it can be ignored. the `and` is just a way to make it more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` is not an expression in CoffeeScript and `and` has the form:

> `expr and expr`

Since `return` is not an expression, you can't say `expr and return` without seeing the error you're seeing.

There are various ways to get around that problem though, which one you choose depends on what you're expecting `foo()` to return and what you want your function to return.

If you don't care what you return, then just get straight to it:

```
return foo() if(condition)
```

Remember that `return` and `return undefined` are the same thing.

If `foo()` returns a truthy value, then you could use `&&` (or `and`) thusly:

```
return foo() && undefined if(condition)
```

If `foo()` returns a falsey value then switch to `||` (or `or`):

```
return foo() || undefined if(condition)
```

If you have no idea what `foo()` will return (if anything), then things get ugly. If CoffeeScript had a [comma operator like JavaScript does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

Then you could say:

```
return foo(), undefined if(condition)
```

That doesn't work because CoffeeScript doesn't have a comma operator. However, you can simulate it with an extra function:

```
comma = (a, b) -> b
#...
return comma(foo(), undefined) if(condition)
```

or an SIF version using `do`:

```
return (do -> foo(); return) if(condition)
```

or you could use backticks to embed raw JavaScript in your CoffeeScript:

```
return `foo(), undefined` if(condition)
```

or you could combine the `&&` and `||` techniques:

```
return (foo() || undefined) && undefined if(condition)
```

Demos: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/UQc7g/

---

I'd lean towards `return foo() if(condition)` with such limited information.